# Run tar command as child_process in Node.js

Tags: node.js, linux, tar

When trying to use child_process.spawn in node.js to run a tar command, runtime fails with `ENOENT` error. 
If I run it as child_process.exec, the command runs and returns one line of output through `exec.stdout.on('data')` event handler. When running the command in a terminal it has more output than what exec is returning.

The key problem is that with the flags `-cvMf` tar requires the user to press enter to continue its process, which I was hoping to do via `exec.send`

Here's an excerpt of the code I have:

```
 try {
  let subprocess = exec('tar -cvMf /dev/nst0 /mnt/Data/2GBdata1 /mnt/Data/1GBdata');

  subprocess.stdout.on('data', function (data)  {
    console.log('stdout on data: \n', data.toString());
  });
  subprocess.on('data', function(data)  {
    console.log('on data: \n', data);
  })
  subprocess.stdout.on('message', function (message)  {
    console.log('sub messgae: ', message);
  });
  subprocess.stderr.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('sub error thrown', err);
    throw err;
  })
  subprocess.on('exit', function (data)  {
    subprocess = null;
    console.log('sub exited: \n', data);
  });

}
catch (err) {
  console.error(`exec error: ${err}`);
  output = `${err}`;
}
```

The output is simply:

```
 stdout on data: 
 /mnt/Data/2GBdata1

stdout on data: 
 /mnt/Data/1GBdata
```

Then the process simply hangs.
The expected output (when running the command in terminal) is the following:

```
tar -cvMf /dev/nst0 /mnt/Data/2GBdata /mnt/Data/1GBdata
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
/mnt/Data/2GBdata
/mnt/Data/1GBdata
Prepare volume #2 for ‘/dev/nst0’ and hit return:
```

My last option will be to write a shell script and use execFile, but I'd like to avoid over-complicating things if possible. Any and all help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Update: I managed to run the command using `spawn()` however the line `Prepare volume #2 .. etc` does not register as a 'data' event.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. For whatever reason the line `Prepare volume #2 for ‘/dev/nst0’ and hit return:` doesn't register as a stout event. However upon further research I found that tar has a [-F flag,](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#g_t_002d_002dinfo_002dscript) which allows you to define a script to be ran when it reaches the end of the tape.
I wrote a simple shell script that echos when the end of a tape is reached, which then registers as an stdout event.
With this, I was able to continue my project without any hassle.
The command now looks like this:

```
tar -F './tartest.sh' -cvMf /dev/nst0 '(data files here)'
```